# How to be notified when Internet Explorer gets focus

Tags: c#, .net, active-window

I'm working on a project in which I want my program to be notified when Internet Explorer gets focus or when navigating through tabs. To be clearer when an instance of IE gets focus or the user selects another tab, I want my program to be notified.

I just tried to do this using `AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler` as I mentioned in my previous question: [AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler does not always fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270543/automationfocuschangedeventhandler-does-not-always-fire)  .  But it seems not to be working appropriately with tab interactions.

(It seems my previous question was very specific, So I tried to make it more general)

So I want to know if there is a way that my application can be notified when Internet explorer gain focus or the user selects different tab in the same instance of IE?

Or if it is still very specific, Is there any way which my program can be notified when focus changed?

Comment: Your app is a stand-alone process and not a browser plug-in, correct?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/ActiveApplicationWatcher01252007024921AM/ActiveApplicationWatcher.aspx) is a similar app. See whether it helps.

```
//This Function is used to get Handle for Active Window...
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public static IntPtr getforegroundWindow()
{
    //This method is used to get Handle for Active Window using GetForegroundWindow() method present in  
    user32.dll
    return GetForegroundWindow();
}
```